# Dynamically get the database name from a Databricks DLT pipeline

Tags: databricks, delta-live-tables

How do I dynamically get the database name from a DLT pipeline?

Comment: I'm not sure that there is an easy way to do that. For what purpose do you need it?

Comment: separation of dev vs production databases

Comment: let me elaborate, I have to separate a single DLT pipeline into two separate DLT pipelines because DLT doesn't have support for ignoreChanges. ignoreChanges is needed because we have to delete source data in order to comply with data privacy laws. the second DLT pipeline would need to load the output of the first DLT pipeline with spark.readStream(f"{database}.{table_name}") and I'd like to easily switch to a dev database without impacting the production pipeline.

Comment: How did you resolve? were you able to get the database name dynamically?